# c++11 use std::map as return value

Tags: c++11, stl, move

I usually return an object of std::vector or std::map as an incoming reference paremeter(as funcVec2 and funcMap2 below). But it is a bit inconvenient when writing codes. So I think if I can use return value under c++11(as funcVec1 and funcMap1 below) because it will call move constructor but not copy constructor, so it maybe still spend only one construct time and no deconstruct as the form of incoming reference paremeter.
But I write the codes below to verify it and it turns out that funcVec1 and funcMap1 takes more times then funcVec2 and funcMap2. So I am confused now why funcVec1 and funcMap1 takes so long?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std;
vector<int> funcVec1() {
    vector<int >vec;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        vec.push_back(i);
    }
    return vec;
}

void funcVec2(vector<int>&vec) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        vec.push_back(i);
    }
    return;
}

map<int, int> funcMap1() {
    map<int, int>tmpMap;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        tmpMap[i] = i;
    }
    return tmpMap;
}

void funcMap2(map<int, int>&tmpMap) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        tmpMap[i] = i;
    }
}

int main()
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    system_clock::time_point t1 = system_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i) {
        vector<int> vec1 = funcVec1();
    }
    auto t2 = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    cout << "return vec takes " << (t2 - t1).count() << " tick count" << endl;
    cout << duration_cast<milliseconds>(t2 - t1).count() << " milliseconds" << endl;
    cout << " --------------------------------" << endl;
    vector<int> vec2;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i) {
        funcVec2(vec2);
    }
    auto t3 = system_clock::now();
    cout << "reference vec takes " << (t3 - t2).count() << " tick count" << endl;
    cout << duration_cast<milliseconds>(t3 - t2).count() << " milliseconds" << endl;
    cout << " --------------------------------" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i) {
        map<int, int> tmpMap1 = funcMap1();
    }
    auto t4 = system_clock::now();
    cout << "return map takes " << (t4 - t3).count() << " tick count" << endl;
    cout << duration_cast<milliseconds>(t4 - t3).count() << " milliseconds" << endl;
    cout << " --------------------------------" << endl;
    map<int, int>tmpMap2;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i) {
        funcMap2(tmpMap2);
    }
    auto t5 = system_clock::now();
    cout << "reference map takes " << (t5 - t4).count() << " tick count" << endl;
    cout << duration_cast<milliseconds>(t5 - t4).count() << " milliseconds" << endl;
    cout << " --------------------------------" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have not played around with the code but i would guess that it's because the fast examples just add data to a single vector/map while the slow ones allocates new vectors/maps for each call. The number of memory allocations should be far more when allocating new containers each time.

Comment: The usual question needs to be asked. Do you have optimization turned on? What compiler and flags are you using?

Comment: Just a new console project with vs2017 without any other additional optimizations @Retired Ninja

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. you are not only meassuring the time for your operations, you also include the printouts. this is suboptimal.
2. you should measure performance in release mode. be aware that you are not doing anything usefull with your objects and the optimizer may throw away most of your code you wanted to measure.
3. the comparisons are not "fair". for example in your map1 case you are constructing an empty map, fill it (memory allocations happen here) and then you throw it away. in the map2 case you are reusing the identical map object over and over again. you are not allocating memory over and over again.